# Hazelcast node getting removed

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am unable to understand as to why a newly created hazelcast node is being removed automatically from the cluster.Does it have anything to do with memory leaking? The logged information is as follows:

```
Members [2] {   
Member [127.0.0.1:5702]     
Member [127.0.0.1:5703] this lite 
>  }
>
```

> [#|2012-11-27T16:23:07.161+1100|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|Project.ConnectionStatusServiceImpl|_ThreadID=66;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|memberRemoved  {Member [127.0.0.1:5701]}|#]
>
> ```
> Members [1] {   
>    Member [127.0.0.1:5703] this lite
> ```
>
> }
>
> [#|2012-11-27T16:23:08.657+1100|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|Project.ConnectionStatusServiceImpl|_ThreadID=66;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|memberRemoved
>   {Member [127.0.0.1:5702]}|#]